# Checking subclass at specific list index

Tags: c#, list, xna, subclass

Hi I'm wondering how you would check if an object at a specific location in a List is equal to something.

I have 3 subclasses of "Ship", they are called "Enemy", "Enemy2", "Player"
All of them are saved in a List that I call "Ships"

I'm wondering how you would check in a list that the item at index is of one of the above. It's pretty hard to explain, I'll try to explain in code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Game1.Ships.Count; i++)
    {
    if(Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i) == "Enemy")
        Enemy e = Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i);
        if (this.collisionBox.Intersects(e.collisionBox))
        {
            e.Destroy(false);
            //Execute Destory(bool).
        }
    }
    else
        i++;
        //Skip to next item.
```

That is roughly what I'm trying to do, obviously I'd need to check that It's not a Player. And I'd also have to do the same loop for Enemy2.
Observe though that "Ship" does not have a Destroy(bool) by default, it's only exsists on "Enemy" & "Enemy2".

Comment: Independent of your question, the `else i++;` is going to cause you problems, as it will result in some ships being skipped. Is this intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `is`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Game1.Ships.Count; i++)
{
    if(Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i) is Enemy)
    {
        Enemy e = (Enemy)Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i);
        if (this.collisionBox.Intersects(e.collisionBox))
        {
            e.Destroy(false);
            //Execute Destory(bool).
        }
    }
    else
        i++;
        //Skip to next item.
}
```

Comment: @Daniel 
I get the following error on 
"Enemy e = Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i);"

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProjectGame1.Ship' to 'ProjectGame1.Enemy'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" If i do that way

Comment: @user669415: Sorry, missed that line. Fixed my answer.

Comment: @Daniel I see how you are thinking, and it does work, but exactly how does the (Enemy) before the Game1.Ships.ElementAt(i) make a difference??

Comment: It's a cast. It tells the compiler that this instance of type `Ship` really is an instance of type `Enemy`.

Comment: +1 for demonstration of the correct technique for a safe cast (that is what is being asked for).  ElementAt is still bad - but that's external to the typing problem.

Comment: @David B: I agree with you and others about `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 0):

and consider

```
 foreach (var e in Game.Ships.OfType<IDestroy>())
     e.Destroy()
```

This would seem to be a nice strategy seeing that

> "Ship" does not
>   have a Destroy(bool) by default, it's
>   only exsists on "Enemy" & "Enemy2"

I you cannot/will not add the interface to make it easy to select the ship types then you could resort to

```
var destroyables = Game.Ships
           .OfType<Enemy>()
     .Concat(
           Game.Ships.OfType<Enemy2>());
```

Do I need to point out which method would have my vote ?

Comment: This isn't semantically the same. It is, however, if you add the missing `where` clause and change `IDestroy` to `Enemy`. If you want to imply, that `Enemy` should implement `IDestroy` while the other classes shouldn't, please explain your reasoning, behind this.

Comment: Adding more detail to post. Note I'm contributing ideas here, not instant-solutions :)

Comment: That's exactly, why I think you should elaborate a bit, because the OP obviously is still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not want to use `ElementAt()` like this, as it iterates over the start of the sequence every time. I would suggest using a `foreach` loop and `OfType<>()` instead:

```
foreach (var e in Game1.Ships.OfType<Enemy>())
{
    if (this.collisionBox.Intersects(e.collisionBox))
        e.Destroy(false);
}
```

Or, if `Game1.Ships` implements `ICollection`, you could use your `for` loop and replace `.ElementAt(i)` with `[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Game1.Ships.Count; i++)
{
    var e = Game1.Ships[i] as Enemy;
    if (e != null)
        if (this.collisionBox.Intersects(e.collisionBox))
            e.Destroy(false);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the foreach loop since it is actively modifying the size of the list thus breaking it. I'm testing your for loop atm though

Comment: If Destroy is actively modifying the list, then you'll want to enumerate over the list backwards: `for(int i = Game1.Ship.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

Or LINQish:

```
var enemiesToDestroy = from enemy in Game1.Ships.OfType<Enemy>()
                       where this.collisionBox.Intersects(enemy.collisionBox)
                       select enemy;
enemiesToDestroy.ToList().ForEach(enemy => enemy.Destroy(false));
```

If you want to get rid of the ToList() conversion, define the following extension method

```
public static void ForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource>   action)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        action (element);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
enemiesToDestroy.ForEach(enemy => enemy.Destroy(false));
```

Comment: wrap your LINQ query in parenthesis and add `ToList()` at the end at it will even compile ;)

Comment: or `enemiesToDestroy.ToList().ForEach(...)`. This will make the query reusable. Of course you should choose the correct approach for the specific situation